# Is there a difference between strong discriminatory functions and discriminatory functions?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have the definition for a discriminatory function, which is:
A bounded function $\phi$ is discriminatory if
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(w \cdot x + b) d \mu(x) = 0 
$$
for all $w \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$ implies $\mu \equiv 0$, where $\mu$ is a finite signed Borel measure.

On the other hand, I have the definition of a strong discriminatory function, which is:
A bounded function $\phi$ is strong discriminatory if
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(f(x)) d \mu(x) = 0 
$$
for all $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^d)$ implies $\mu \equiv 0$, where $\mu$ is a finite signed Borel measure.

Now, discriminatory should imply strong discriminatory, because the integral assumption  $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(w \cdot x + b) d \mu(x) = 0 $ is much weaker than the assumption $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(f(x)) d \mu(x) = 0$.

However, in the book *Deep Learning Architectures. A Mathematical Approach*, by Ovidiu Calin (Exercise 9.8.9) one is supposed to show the reverse direction, which would yield the equivalence between strong discriminatory functions and discriminatory functions.

Am I missing something or is the exercise actually wrong in the book?

**Edit** Adding my (possibly wrong) proof, why discriminatory should imply strong discriminatory. I have to prove:
$$
\forall f \in C(\mathbb{R}^d): \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(f(x))d\mu(x) = 0 \quad \implies \quad \mu \equiv 0
$$
So, by assumption I have $\forall f \in C(\mathbb{R}^d): \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(f(x))d\mu(x) = 0$. This obviously implies $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(w \cdot x + b) d \mu(x) = 0$ for all $w \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Since I am also assuming that $\phi$ is discriminatory, I have $\mu \equiv 0$, which proves the statement.

**New Edit**

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of finite, signed Borel Measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

A bounded function $\phi$ is called discriminatory $:\iff$
$$
\forall \mu \in \mathcal{M}: \text{ } \underbrace{\left(\forall w \in \mathbb{R}^d, b \in \mathbb{R}: \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \phi(w\cdot x + b) d\mu(x) = 0\right)}_{=:A^d(\mu)} \implies \underbrace{\mu \equiv 0}_{=:B(\mu)}.
$$

A bounded function $\phi$ is called strong discriminatory $:\iff$
$$
\forall \mu \in \mathcal{M}: \text{ } \underbrace{\left(\forall f \in C(\mathbb{R}^d): \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \phi(f(x)) d\mu(x) = 0\right)}_{=:A^s(\mu)} \implies \underbrace{\mu \equiv 0}_{=:B(\mu)}.
$$

Here $A^d(\mu), A^s(\mu)$ and $B(\mu)$ are all statements, depending on a $\mu \in \mathcal{M}$.

I observe that for a given $\mu \in \mathcal{M}$, I have $A^s(\mu) \implies A^d(\mu)$, since $x \mapsto w \cdot x + b \in C(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Now I want to prove: A discriminatory function is strong discriminatory, i.e.
$$
\underbrace{\left(\forall \mu \in \mathcal{M}: A^d(\mu) \implies B(\mu)\right)}_{=:E} \implies \underbrace{\left(\forall \mu \in \mathcal{M}: A^s(\mu) \implies B(\mu)\right)}_{=:F}.
$$
Per Definition $E$ is the statement that $\phi$ is discriminatory and $F$ is the statement that $\phi$ is strong discriminatory, so $E \implies F$ is the statement claimed above. So I have to prove $F$ and I can assume $E$.

I prove $F$ like this: I take an arbitrary $\mu \in \mathcal{M}$. Now, I have to prove $A^s(\mu) \implies B(\mu)$. So, I have to show $B(\mu)$ and I can assume $A^s(\mu)$.

Since I can assume $A^s(\mu)$, from above I have $A^d(\mu)$. But I also assume $E$, which, since $A^d(\mu)$, lets me follow $B(\mu)$, which is what I wanted. This concludes the proof.

Comment: Why should discriminatory $\implies $ strong discriminatory? You haven't provided proof of that. On the other hand, proving exercise 9.8.9.(a) is straightforward.

Comment: I have edited my post and provided a proof, which hopefully is correct. Maybe I am misunderstanding the definition of (strong) discriminatory?

Comment: Your proof seems inaccurate to me. I will edit the tags.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate, why it is wrong/inaccurate?

Comment: To prove discriminatory $\implies$ strong discriminatory, you have start with $\phi$ being discriminatory, and from that show it meets the conditions of strong discriminatory. What your proof shows is the converse: that strong discriminatory $\implies$ discriminatory, which is exactly what one would expect from the names. One other matter, "proof" is a noun. The verb is "prove".

Comment: I am very sorry, but I really want to understand where my mistake is. I have written a more formal proof of my claimed statement that any discriminatory function is strong discriminatory. Maybe you can point out, where my misconception is in the above proof I wrote (Maybe a definition?). Thank you!

Comment: **"Now, I have to prove $A^s(\mu)\implies B(\mu)$. So, I have to show $B(\mu)$ and I can assume $A^s(\mu)$"**: I think the inaccuracy might be here. You cannot assume $A^s(\mu)$; you have to prove that $F$ *entirely* follows from $E$ (in an intuitive sense). I am sure some analysts or formal logic or proof theory people can pile in and tell you exactly how your logic is flawed. I will upvote and edit the tags once more.

Comment: But regardless of $E$, I want to show a simple implication $A \implies B$. If $A$ would not be true (i.e. I do not assume $A$), then there is nothing to show. So, I should be able to assume $A$. 
(Sorry, I am still quite new on stack exchange) Should I perhaps start a new post, reducing my problem to the logic, which causes the problems?
Or does someone have some references where strong discriminatory functions are mentioned/used?